# Is that possible to nest a slack channel inside another slack channel?

Tags: slack

Say, I have a channel named `teamA`, and also got a channel named `subTeamB`, and `subTeamB` is actually a sub-team of team A, e.g. all members in `subTeamB` included in `teamA`.

In this case, is that possible to have `subTeamB` nested inside `teamA`?

Answer (score 10):

No, you can not have channels within a channel in Slack.

As a workaround you could name the channels in a way that they reflect sub-channels.

Examples:

```
#teamA-subTeamA
#teamA-subTeamB
```

This is also what Slack recommends on its documentation page about [Organizing and naming channels](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/217626408-Organizing-and-naming-channels).

Comment: In https://slackhq.com/advice-for-large-teams-on-slack they also say "Channel naming conventions are key", so I'll go with `topic_subtopic` and topic/subtopic would be `word1-word2-...`, also I believe once subchannel is created, it should be linked in main channel...

Answer (score 5):

They did say they were working on it, or something to better organize:
https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/503652089755873280

> Makes sense. We're exploring better ways to organize / group large
>   amounts of channels. Stay tuned! ✨
>
> — Slack (@SlackHQ) January
>   9, 2016

Comment: 4 years  later, is there some update? It's not really covered  in https://slackhq.com/advice-for-large-teams-on-slack. Thanks!